# Overloaded method value table with alternatives

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have following code the compiler complains:

```
val state: KTable[String, String]  = builder
  .table("BARY-PATH", Materialized.as("PATH-STORE"))
```

Error message:

```
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/paths-stream/src/main/scala/io/khinkali/PathsTopology.scala:23:8: overloaded method value table with alternatives:
[error]   [K, V](x$1: String, x$2: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized[K,V,org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes,Array[Byte]]])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable[K,V] <and>
[error]   [K, V](x$1: String, x$2: org.apache.kafka.streams.Consumed[K,V])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable[K,V]
[error]  cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing])
[error]       .table("BARY-PATH", Materialized.as("PATH-STORE"))
[error]        ^
```

Then I tried:

```
val state: KTable[String, String]  = builder
  .table[String, String]("BARY-PATH", Materialized[String, String,KeyValueStore[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes, Array[Byte]]].as("PATH-STORE"))
```

The compiler still complains:

```
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/microservices/paths-stream/src/main/scala/io/khinkali/PathsTopology.scala:24:43: object org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized is not a value
[error]       .table[String, String]("BARY-PATH", Materialized[String, String,KeyValueStore[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes, Array[Byte]]].as("PATH-STORE"))
```

I read the [API docs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html) but could not figure, what am I doing wrong?

The method implementation:

```
 * Materialize a {@link StateStore} with the given name.
 *
 * @param storeName  the name of the underlying {@link KTable} state store; valid characters are ASCII
 * alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-'.
 * @param <K>       key type of the store
 * @param <V>       value type of the store
 * @param <S>       type of the {@link StateStore}
 * @return a new {@link Materialized} instance with the given storeName
 */
public static <K, V, S extends StateStore> Materialized<K, V, S> as(final String storeName) {
    Topic.validate(storeName);
    return new Materialized<>(storeName);
}
```

In Java, I did

```
KTable<String, String> soureTable = builder
    .table("BARY-PATH", Materialized.as("PATH-STORE"));
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: The `Nothing`s in `(String, org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing])` looks suspicious to me. Check `Materialized` is what you really think it is.

Comment: How to substitute the type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try moving generic types specification after `as` method:

```
val state: KTable[String, String]  = builder
    .table[String, String]("BARY-PATH", Materialized.as[String, String,KeyValueStore[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes, Array[Byte]]]("PATH-STORE"))
```

as you may see from the Java signature, for static methods you should specify generic types for the method rather than for the class.