# Not able to apply selectKey on kafka stream

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to write a simple filtering logic with kafka stream but getting an error everytime with selectKey method and not able to procedd further.

```
val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
    val textLines: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream[String, String](inputTopic)

    val filteredValue: KStream[String, String] =  textLines.
    filter((key: String, value: String) => value.contains(","))
     .selectKey[String]((key: String, value: String) => value.split(",")(0).toLowerCase)
```

Error:

```
overloaded method value selectKey with alternatives: (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: String, _ >: String, _ <: String],x$2: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named)org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream[String,String] <and> (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: String, _ >: String, _ <: String])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream[String,String] cannot be applied to ((String, String) ⇒ String)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala you sometimes need to specify the exact type bindings, because type inference will not work as you're used to in Scala. 
When you find these typing errors, a rule of thumb you can apply is to separate lines with new explicitly typed vals, until you find the place where you need to specify the type.

Similar issues and solutions:

```
The compiler need some help to infer the correct type for the aggregator parameter.

To make it compile you can try:

val store: Materialized[String, String, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]] = ???

private def save(pea: KStream[String, String]): Unit = {
  val aggregator: Aggregator[String, String, String] = (_, _, value: String) => value
  pea
    .groupByKey()
    .aggregate(() => """{folder: ""}""",
      aggregator,
      store)
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145527/overloaded-method-value-aggregate-with-alternatives).

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458725/overloaded-method-value-table-with-alternatives) is another one in Java that illustrates a different flavour of strict typing in Kafka Streams too:

```
Try moving generic types specification after as method:

val state: KTable[String, String]  = builder
    .table[String, String]("BARY-PATH", Materialized.as[String, String,KeyValueStore[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes, Array[Byte]]]("PATH-STORE"))
```

as you may see from the Java signature, for static methods you should specify generic types for the method rather than for the class.

You may find many other examples out there, even outside Kafka Streams, about explicit typing needs in Scala.

Comment: it's highly recommended to copy code snippets for the solution from external web pages directly into the answer (still keep the link for reference). The link might break at some point in the future and this would make your answer "useless". If you copy the relevant content, you can avoid this issue.